# Cannot patch sqlalchemy database engine

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy (note: not Flask_SQLAlchemy) for a python 3 project, and I'm trying to write tests for the database by patching the engine with a test engine that points to a test database (as opposed to the production database). In the past, I successfully patched Session, and had working tests, but I recently switched to using the "insert" method, which is executed using `engine.execute()`, as opposed to a context managed session scope which was invoked using `with session_scope() as session:`

So heres the setup: I'm using a db_session module to establish a common session to be used by all DB functions:

```
import sys
import os
import logging

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from database.util import managed_session
import config

logger = logging.getLogger('default')

dirname = os.path.dirname
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(__file__)))

engine = create_engine(config.POSTGRES_URI)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def session_scope():
    return managed_session(Session)
```

and then in the crud_function file we have a setup as follows:

```
import logging
import re
from collections import defaultdict

from sqlalchemy import desc
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

from database.db_session import session_scope, engine, Session
from database.models import *
from database.util import windowed_query
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
import pandas as pd

def store_twitter_user(unprotected_row):
    '''
    Creates a TwitterUser object from the given attributes, adds it to the session, and then commits it to the database.
    :param attributes:
    :return:
    '''
    row = defaultdict(lambda: None, unprotected_row)

    pg_upsert(TwitterUser, row)

def pg_upsert(model, row):
    '''Performs an UPDATE OR INSERT ON CONFLICT (Upsert), which is a special SQL command for Postgres dbs.
    More info here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert
    '''
    try:
        insert_stmt = insert(model.__table__).values(row)
        do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(constraint=model.__table__.primary_key, set_=row)
        engine.execute(do_update_stmt)
        logger.debug('New {} stored successfully!'.format(type(object)))
        return True

    except IntegrityError as e:
        if re.search('violates foreign key constraint .* Key \(author_id\)=\(\d+\) is not present in table', str(e.args)):
            # Sends exception to celery task which will retry the task for a certain number of times
            raise

    except Exception as err:
        logger.error('pg_upsert: An error occurred while trying to store the new {}: {}'.format(model.__mapper__, err))
        return False
```

database.models just contains a bunch of classes used to create DB models for SQLAlchemy, like as follows:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
    screen_name = Column(String())
    location = Column(String(), index=True)
    friends_count = Column(Integer)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    time_zone = Column(String())
    lang = Column(String())
```

Now here's the test file:

```
engine = create_engine(config.POSTGRES_TEST_URI)

class TestDBCRUD(unittest.TestCase):
    ClassIsSetup = False
    ReadyForTeardown = False

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Creates all the tables in the test DB
        :return:
        """
        if not self.ClassIsSetup:
            print("SETTING UP!!!")
            Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
            self.__class__.ClassIsSetup = True

    def tearDown(self):
        """
        Deletes all test DB data and destroys the tables after a test is finished
        :return:
        """
        if self.ReadyForTeardown:
            print("TEARING DOWN!!!")
            Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
            self.__class__.ReadyForTeardown = False

    @patch('database.crud.db_crud_functions.Session')
    @patch('database.crud.db_crud_functions.engine', autospec=True)
    @patch('database.db_session.Session')
    @patch('database.db_session.engine', autospec=True)
    def test_00_store_user(self, mock_session_engine, mock_session_Session, mock_engine, mock_session):
        print("testing store user!")
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=engine)
        mock_session_Session.return_value = Session()
        mock_session_engine.return_value = engine
        mock_session.return_value = Session()
        mock_engine.return_value = engine

        user = User(id=6789, screen_name="yeti")
        user_dict = {'id': 6789, 'screen_name': "yeti"}

        store_twitter_user(user_dict)

        with managed_session(Session) as session:
            retrieved_user = session.query(User).first()
            print("users are: {}".format(retrieved_user))
            self.assertEqual(user.id, retrieved_user.id)
            self.assertEqual(user.screen_name, retrieved_user.screen_name)
```

You'll notice a stupid amount of patches on top of the test function, and that is to show that I've tried to patch the engine and session from multiple locations. I've read that patches should be made where objects are used, and not where they are imported from, so I tried to cover all the bases. It doesn't matter, the test function always ends up inserting a user into the production database, and not into the test database. Then, when the retrieval happens, it returns None.

```
File "tests/testdatabase/test_db_crud_functions.py", line 59, in test_00_store_user
    self.assertEqual(user.id, retrieved_user.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Again, before pg_upsert was added, I used:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    session.add(something_here)
```

And session was successfully mocked to point to POSTGRES_TEST_URI, and not POSTGRES_URI. I'm at a loss here, please let me know if anything sticks out. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a separate set of settings/config for running the tests that always uses a dummy DB, or an in-memory SQLite etc?

Comment: @TomDalton In what sense? I do have a separate config, as in a separate URI and database name, but the CRUD functions themselves are built to import the settings/config from db_session.py. I wanted to patch over everything in db_session with the test DB session and engine that I create in the test file.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you are trying to mock out all the DB stuff in the first place. E.g. Why not run your tests against a separate Postgres DB, or if that's too slow, use an in-memory SQLite DB or similar.

Comment: We are trying to run it against a different database, but the code implicitly calls the production database (as in the URI is hardcoded in), so i need to trick it somehow.

Comment: The URI of the DB shouldn't be hardcoded, that should be be part of the config. Then you can change it for the test config.

Comment: In your code above you use `import config; .... config.POSTGRES_URI`. Is config just a module that essentially contains constants?

Comment: You should take a look at using something like configparser. `https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html` Your config module can read e.g. an environment variable that tells it which config file to use. If the env var is not set then default to reading your production config file. That way you can do `export MY_CONFIG=settings.test; <cmd to run tests>`

Comment: This article https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b has a good explanation (see the second section "Using external configuration file" for more info on what I'm suggesting), but the other methods might work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the links, this does look like an easier way to do it. Out of curiosity, can you think of why my patching is not working?

Comment: No, but from the stacktrace it looks like you should easily be able to trace back where the unexpected `None` value actually comes from.

Comment: I know where it comes from, it's because there is no User in the test DB for it to retrieve. The thing i'm confused about is why i cannot patch the SQLAlchemy successfully, thereby causing the tests to store a User in the production DB and not the test DB.